# Why does Postfix accept MAIL FROM from an email it's not responsible for

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I'm testing a postfix installation. I noticed that if I try to send mail from a fictitious account on another domain that isn't mine (`unknown@NotMyDomain.com`), to one of my local users (`user@MyDomain.com`), the email still gets delivered to my user.

```
MAIL FROM:<unknown@notmydomain.com>

RCPT TO:<user@mydomain.com>
```

I'm not sure if this is normal behaviour or if it can cause problems. For example, I'm worried that users could use the server to send spoofed emails that aren't really originating from the email accounts they claim to be originating from.

P.S. I'm still in the early stages of learning postfix, so not sure if my question makes sense.

---

As per @DerfK's comment, I tested for an open relay (where both `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` aren't hosted on this server), and this is what I get. For some reason it accepts the `RCPT TO`, then says goodbye **AFTER** I type the subject. So is this good or bad?

```
HELO test.mydomain.com
250 mail
MAIL FROM:<user@notmydomain1.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<user@notmydomain2.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
Subject: testing for open relay
221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: `I'm worried that users could use the server to send spoofed emails that aren't really originating from the email accounts they claim to be originating from.` If you want to run a mail server, you have to be prepared to police its use. If you aren't willing to do that, then you shouldn't be running a mail server and should instead let your ISP do it.

Comment: @David Schwartz, But isn't this why I'm asking questions?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm just saying you may wish to reconsider your decision to run your own mail server. It's *not* "set and forget". It has to be policed.

Comment: @David Schwartz, Actually, I'm not planning to run my own mail server, but I have to learn it.

Comment: You're not sending the message from a machine on the same subnet are you? Usually by default postfix will accept and attempt to deliver those.

Answer (score 10):

You forgot Data! I had exactly this problem. You have to have command data, then subject. So it resolves your problems. Look like this:

```
HELO test.mydomain.com

250 mail

MAIL FROM:<user@notmydomain1.com>

250 2.1.0 Ok

RCPT TO:<user@notmydomain2.com>

250 2.1.5 Ok

Data

354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

subject: hello

i love you, oh my god! Why do i forget data

.

250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E10601E09B1

quit
```

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me from a major headache. Was already prepared to bang my head against the wall. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

That is normal behaviour.  Other SMTP servers connect to yours as SMTP clients to deliver mail to your domain.

To work around this spoofing problem, there are SPF and DKIM.  You should check them out.

Comment: Definitely normal.  Now, you should worry when you can send mail from not-your-domain, to not-your-domain. In that case you have an open relay.

Comment: @DerfK, I tested this. See my update for what I got. Is this output good or bad?

Comment: @sameold you're getting kicked off because you're speaking SMTP wrong.  Try `DATA` after `RCPT TO:` then if it's going to accept the email, it will tell you to write it one line at a time, then finish with a line starting with `.`.  This is where you'd put Subject: and other header/body content.  Once you get to the `.` if it says OK, then you have a real problem.  See the example on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)

Answer (score 6):

Concerning your first situation: it's normal for SMTP server to accept mail for accounts it is responsible for and basically that is how it's going to work, just setup spam checking software like SpamAssassin (most widely used free solution, supports SPF/DKIM check).

As far as your question likely appeared on early stage of mail server setup, here are some tips related to dealing with fictitious mail.

Normal users won't try to spoof their emails in most cases. More often this is behavior of spammer that is why you can filter such mail based on its content.
More complex setup can include:

1. [RBL/DNSBL/RHSBL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) checking (may give many false rejects because many of even valid mail senders break some of RFCs).
2. Sender address verification (see [Address verification readme](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html) for Postfix). This also might reject some of valid mail (basically again because of misconfiguration, e.g. disallowing mail with empty `MAIL FROM: <>`).
3. [Greylisting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting). As for my personal experience this fights up to 90% of spam mails because of spammers impatience. But this slows delivery of valid mail a bit however this is not a problem in most cases.
4. SPF/DKIM verification (although not mandatory to support it).
5. Various custom content checking (including already mentioned spamcheckers).

If we talk about postfix it gives rather flexible abilities to restrict which mail is acceptable.

Concerning your update: the error message postfix gives you just states that you break SMTP specs (there is no `Subject:` SMTP command, see [SMTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) but `Subject` header you've likely meant is part of message body which must be supplied after `DATA` SMTP command).
From the transcript you've provided I can't reliably tell whether your postfix functions as open relay because there is no information about client who had that SMTP session.

With basic setup postfix, as far as I recall, allows relay of mail (meaning you can specify any email address, not only in domain which postfix is responsible for) from:

- localhost
- trusted networks (set via mynetworks)

So if you've telneted postfix from the server it runs on that might be ok. If from anywhere in Internet then things are bad.

Also you might want to read carefully [SMTPD Relay and access control](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) to deepen the knowledge exactly on topic of postfix relay access.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix must accept mail from domains it is not responsible for. Otherwise you would have only local email.

An open relay accepts mail from domains it is not responsible for to addresses it is not responsible for.   In the following table: Local represents domains the sever is responsible for; Remote represents domains the server is not responsible for; and None represents an empty sender:

```
Source   Destination   Accepted
======   ===========   ========
Local    Local         Yes
Local    Remote        Yes
Remote   Local         Yes
Remote   Remote        NO
None     Local         Yes
None     Remote        NO
```

There are many ways to verify the Remote domain including: Callouts, SPF, DMARC, Whitelists and Blacklists.  These all depend on DNS.  Greylisting is a technique to ensure a real mail server is sending the mail rather than a spambot.  Spamfilters such a Spamassassin use a combination of techniques to validate the mail which usually includes scoring the above tests as well as content and headers.